# Discord.js "voiceStateUpdate" called twice

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to create a temporary channel what is working with "Slash" commands. I am almost there but I am getting an error when creating a second channel because the "**voiceStateUpdate**" is getting called twice.

```
else if (commandName === "createchannel") {
   var channelName = options.getString("channelname");
   var rolesThatCanJoin = options.getRole("roles");
   var state = options.getString("state");
   var channel = interection.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
        type: "GUILD_VOICE"
        }).then((channel) => { 
        channel.setParent("670691620844470320")
        createdChannelID = channel.id;

        interection.reply({
          content: `**Channel named:** ${channelName}\n**Role that can join:** ${rolesThatCanJoin}\n**State:** ${state}`,
                ephemeral: true,
                })

        client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
            var newChannelID = newState.channelId;
                
            if (newChannelID === createdChannelID) {
              console.log("User has joined voice channel with id " + newChannelID);
            } 
            else {
               console.log("User has left");
               channel.delete()
            }
         });
      });
    }
```

Console:

```
User has joined voice channel with id 936252040865284156
User has left
User has joined voice channel with id 936252068568641576
User has joined voice channel with id 936252068568641576
User has left
User has left

Error:
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like every time the command runs, you are calling `client.on('voiceStateUpdate'...` again, which adds another listener. This is causing you to receive the same event multiple times. I suggest you move your `client.on('voiceStateUpdate'...` code to another location where it will get called once, same as how you are handling other events like `client.on('messageCreate'...` or `client.on('interactionCreate'...`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now its working like it sould.